# 32 Bit CRC calculation not matching with online generator

Tags: c, crc32

Can somebody help me in this calculation of 32 bit CRC.

This is the peice of code I used for 32 bit CRC calculation.

```
static unsigned int crc32_table[256];

void make_crc_table()
{
   int j;
   unsigned int crc,byte, mask;

   /* Set up the table, if necessary. */
   if (crc32_table[1] == 0)
   {
      for (byte = 0; byte <= 255; byte++)
      {
         crc = byte;
         for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--)   // Do eight times
         {
            mask = -(crc & 1);
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & mask);
         }
         crc32_table[byte] = crc;
      }
   }

   for (j=0;j<10;j++)
      printf("crc32_table[%d] = %x\n",j,crc32_table[j]);
}

unsigned int crc32cx(unsigned int crc,unsigned char *message,int len)
{
   unsigned int word;

   do
   {
     if((word = *(unsigned int *)message) & 0xFF)
     {
       crc = crc ^ word;
       crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[crc & 0xFF];
       crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[crc & 0xFF];
       crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[crc & 0xFF];
       crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[crc & 0xFF];
       message = message + 4;
       len--;
     }
   }while(len == 0);

   return ~crc;
}

main()
{
   unsigned int crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   unsigned char buff[100] = ABCDEFGH;
   int len;  // lenght in bytes

   len = (((strlen(buff)%8)==0) ? (strlen(buff)/8) : ((strlen(buff)/8)+1));
   printf("lenght in bytes %d\n",len);

   make_crc_table();
   printf("crc = %x\n",crc32cx(crc,buff,len));
}
```

Can somebody help me why this is not matching with online 32 bit CRC calculator. Link given below

http://www.tahapaksu.com/crc/

For input buff=12345678, my CRC is getting matched with the online one.
For other values like buff = ABCD1234, the output is not matching.

Thanks.

Comment: To help others help you, please add a language tag for this question.

Comment: Following your link to Lammert Bies, he makes a library available. You can check your solution against that library.

Comment: Instead of declaring your `unsigned char buff[100] = ABCDEFGH;`you should use quotation marks like `unsigned char buff[100] = "ABCDEFGH";`

Comment: @Frodo I'm sure it's not the quotation marks that are the problem; the code won't even compile without them:)

Comment: How does `mask = -(crc & 1);` make any sense? All numbers involved are unsigned.

Comment: @Pandrei The lack of quotation marks is a very valid concern, since it suggests that this is not the real code, but something else.

Comment: @user3654 can you please edit the question body to show how you were calling the CRC function for the two cases  '12345678', 'ABCD1234'; just do both in the same main call and add the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the way the code is written; let me explain:

```
unsigned int crc32cx(unsigned int crc,unsigned char *message,int len)
{
   unsigned int word;

   do
   {
     if((word = *(unsigned int *)message) & 0xFF)
     {
       crc = crc ^ word;
       crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[crc & 0xFF];
       crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[crc & 0xFF];
       crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[crc & 0xFF];
       crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[crc & 0xFF];
       message = message + 4;
       len--;
     }
   }while(len == 0);

   return ~crc;
}
```

What this function does is to read 4 chars at a time and them compute the CRC (XOR operation); [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) explains the math behind it.
But you do this operation **len** times

```
unsigned char buff[100] = ABCDEFGH;
int len;  // lenght in bytes
printf("crc = %x\n",crc32cx(crc,buff,4));
```

So in your case, you will read 4x4 bytes; And your buffer will contain:

```
buff = ['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' 'G' 'H' '\n' 'trash' 'trash'.... ]
```

You have 8 bytes of information, followed by a '\n' since you are assigning the buffer a string, than trash, since the buffer is allocated on the stack. And you are reading 16 bytes. 
   I'm sure you can spot the problem by now, but just in case, I think that **crc32cx(crc,buff,2)** should solve your issue.

Comment: I am sorry, it is a typo that printf("crc = %x\n",crc32cx(crc,buff,4));Actually I called crc32cx(crc,buff,len); In that case crc32cx(crc,buff,2) and crc32cx(crc,buff,len=1) due to do while are one and the same.

Comment: Will there be a difference in calculation 32 bit CRC algorithm if the input message is more than 1 byte ?

Comment: @user3654 yes there will be a difference; len is the length in unsigned ints, not bytes. You read 4 bytes at a time when computing the CRC. if your buffer only has one byte, the rest will be filled with whatever is on the stack; not 0s

Answer (score 0):

Your CRC code is very nonstandard. When doing a table method you are suppose to input the data byte by byte, not 4 byte chunk by chunk which is definitely causing some input and logic issues. The biggest one being this line `if(word = *(unsigned int *)message) & 0xFF)` which is completely unnecessary and will ignore valid incoming data in some scenarios.

A nice, simple, and clean crc32 C implementation can be [seen here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/libkern/crc32.c). After looking at it and yours and making a few tweaks it worked.

In your function you would change the loop and your variable to:

```
   unsigned char word;
   do
   {
       word = *message;
       crc = crc ^ word;
       crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crc32_table[crc & 0xFF];
       message++;
       len--;

   }while(len > 0);
```

And now in your main you can find the length of your input data just using `len = strlen(buff)`.